# Dual boot upgrade

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, 11.04, windows-vista

I asked:

I have a dual-boot system with Windows Vista and Ubuntu 11.04.  I'd like to upgrade the Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS.  Can I do it?  And how can I do it so that the Windows Vista partition remains intact?

This question received a "duplicate" marking incorrectly.  My question is not about simply upgrading from 11.04 to 14.04 LTS; I know that requires three steps.  It's about doing it on a dual-boot system, without disturbing the Windows partition.  Can this be done?  And how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you have your version of Ubuntu installed. If it's on a separate partition, you could just get the installation on a disk and run the installation and just run it under 'upgrade.' It will then do the update from there off of the disk itself. You could also just install over the older version with the newer version of ubuntu. WARNING! if you install over an older version, it is wise to back up your personal documents of either a flash drive, CD/DVD, or Ubuntu Cloud.